# How can I rewrite this without using if statement?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to rewrite this code without using any if statement.

Is it possible to do that ?

How can I use case or something else ?

```
IF @BrandFilter = ''
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM
        (
            SELECT
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY  
                CASE WHEN @SortType = '1' THEN mt.Ad END ASC,
                CASE WHEN @SortType = '2' THEN mt.Ad END DESC,
                CASE WHEN @SortType = '3' THEN mt.Fiyat END ASC,
                CASE WHEN @SortType = '4' THEN mt.Fiyat END DESC) AS RowNr, * 
            FROM @MainTable mt
            WHERE mt.Fiyat > @MinPrice AND mt.Fiyat < @MaxPrice     
        ) Result
        WHERE RowNr > ((@PageNr-1) * 10) AND RowNr <= ((@PageNr) * 10)  
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM
        (
            SELECT
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY  
                CASE WHEN @SortType = '1' THEN mt.Ad END ASC,
                CASE WHEN @SortType = '2' THEN mt.Ad END DESC,
                CASE WHEN @SortType = '3' THEN mt.Fiyat END ASC,
                CASE WHEN @SortType = '4' THEN mt.Fiyat END DESC) AS RowNr, * 
            FROM @MainTable mt
            WHERE mt.Fiyat > @MinPrice AND mt.Fiyat < @MaxPrice
            AND mt.MarkaId IN (SELECT bf.Data FROM dbo.Split(@BrandFilter, ',') bf)
        ) Result
        WHERE RowNr > ((@PageNr-1) * 10) AND RowNr <= ((@PageNr) * 10)  
    END
```

This code is the difference,

```
AND mt.MarkaId IN (SELECT bf.Data FROM dbo.Split(@BrandFilter, ',') bf)
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY  
        CASE WHEN @SortType = '1' THEN mt.Ad END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @SortType = '2' THEN mt.Ad END DESC,
        CASE WHEN @SortType = '3' THEN mt.Fiyat END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @SortType = '4' THEN mt.Fiyat END DESC) AS RowNr, * 
    FROM @MainTable mt
    WHERE mt.Fiyat > @MinPrice AND mt.Fiyat < @MaxPrice
    AND (@BrandFilter = '' or mt.MarkaId IN (SELECT bf.Data FROM dbo.Split(@BrandFilter, ',') bf))
) Result
WHERE RowNr > ((@PageNr-1) * 10) AND RowNr <= ((@PageNr) * 10)
```

you have to add check if `@brandfilter` is not empty before splitting it

```
(@BrandFilter = '' or mt.MarkaId IN (SELECT bf.Data FROM dbo.Split(@BrandFilter, ',') bf))
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY  
            CASE WHEN @SortType = '1' THEN mt.Ad END ASC,
            CASE WHEN @SortType = '2' THEN mt.Ad END DESC,
            CASE WHEN @SortType = '3' THEN mt.Fiyat END ASC,
            CASE WHEN @SortType = '4' THEN mt.Fiyat END DESC) AS RowNr, * 
    FROM @MainTable mt
    WHERE mt.Fiyat > @MinPrice AND mt.Fiyat < @MaxPrice     
     AND (mt.MarkaId IN (SELECT bf.Data FROM dbo.Split(@BrandFilter, ',') bf) OR @BrandFilter = '')
) Result
WHERE RowNr > ((@PageNr-1) * 10) AND RowNr <= ((@PageNr) * 10)
```

In the upper branch of your `if`, the `AND` portion of the `WHERE` clause is missing; in the lower branch it is the check of `MarkaId` to be part of `@BrandFilter` string. The `OR` condition makes that same condition true when `@BrandFilter` is not specified.